# Signal 1 SIGARBT Crash (PlaySound?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I started getting this error when I tried to make a button play a sound. I'm not getting a code errors (Red or Yellow markers) but my app crashes when I click the button.

Here's what the console outputs:

```
2014-05-12 20:24:59.866 ReAct[4511:60b] -[ViewController PlayAudioBUtton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9059280
2014-05-12 20:24:59.875 ReAct[4511:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController PlayAudioBUtton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9059280'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c6c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019eb8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01d09243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01c5c50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01c5c0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019fd880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x006ad3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x006ad345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x007aebd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x007aefc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x007ae243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x006ecddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    12  UIKit                               0x006ed9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    13  UIKit                               0x006bf5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x006a9353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01bf577f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01bf510b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01c121ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01c119d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01c117eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x031ac5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x031ac42b GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x006abf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  ReAct                               0x000020cd main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02996701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I think it's due to the first description:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController PlayAudioBUtton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9059280'"

But I'm unsure of what this means because I am new to Xcode and iOS coding alike.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means your `ViewController` class doesn't have a method named `PlayAudioButton:`. Perhaps you have a method that is actually named `PlayAudioButton` (with no colon).

Comment: Double check ViewController to see whether it implements PlayAudioBUtton function or not.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized I had a typo on my PlayAudioButton ID. Thanks again.